# Running matlab function from CLI

Tags: linux, matlab, command-line-interface

I wrote a simple `.m` file and tried to run with on the command line without graphics.

Here is `mymax.m`:

```
max =  n1
if(n2 > max)
    max = n2
end
exit
```

However, when I try to run it via the command line, it says something and I can not see the computed values:

```
$ /export/apps/mathematics/matlab2015b/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -r mymax\(2,4\)

                                    < M A T L A B (R) >
                          Copyright 1984-2015 The MathWorks, Inc.
                           R2015b (8.6.0.267246) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                      August 20, 2015


To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

Attempt to execute SCRIPT mymax as a function:
/home/mahmood/matlab-test/mymax.m

>>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: You're calling `mymax` with two input arguments (2 and 4) but it's a script which can't accept any input arguments. You'll need to change it to a function `function mx = mymax(n1, n2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're calling `mymax` as if it were a function (by providing input arguments); however, it is a script which can't accept input arguments. You have two options

**Make it  Function**

```
function mx = mymax(n1, n2)
    mx = n1;

    if n2 > mx
        mx = n2;
    end
end
```

Then from the command line

```
$ matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -r "mymax(2,4); exit"
```

**Initialize `n1` and `n2`**

Your script relies on the variables `n1` and `n2` existing in the global workspace. You will need to define these variables prior to executing the script.

The `-r` flag allows you to specify any MATLAB command at the command line to be run. You can initialize the values of `n1` and `n2` by simply inserting those commands before calling the script (just like you would in a typical MATLAB session).

```
$ matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -r "n1 = 2; n2 = 4; mymax"
```

### Missing output

The reason that you are not seeing any computed values is because you aren't actually returning them or doing anything useful with them. You could add a `disp` statement if you want to see these values. Or if you need them for something else, you can always write them out to a file that is accessible by the other software.

The other option is to write *all* command window output to a log file using the `-logfile` option.

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash -logfile log.txt -r "mymax(2,4); exit"
```

Comment: Are you sure the last line is a working one? `Error in mymax (line 2)` (max =  n1)

Comment: @mahmood Can you post the entire error? Also do not name your variable `max` as that is a built-in function name and could be complicating things

Comment: Using the exact function definition as yours and running the last command, I see `Not enough input arguments` \ `Error in mymax (line 2)` \ `max =  n1;`

Comment: @mahmood The second example assumes that you are using a *script* (like you currently have). The first example is using a function (like the one that I posted above)

Comment: OK I understand. `"mymax(2,4); exit"` is fine